# Setting maximum upload size with deform.widget.FileUploadWidget

Tags: pyramid, deform, colander

How one can limit maximum upload size with deform.widget.FileUploadWidget() so that the validation fails with a friendly error message if the file is too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [code from Kotti](https://github.com/Kotti/kotti_contactform/blob/master/kotti_contactform/views.py#L144) can help. The answer seems to be a custom validator.